# How to add a member in custom object within a do while

Tags: powershell, custom-object

Its a short question but i have some problems understanding customobjects in powershell.

I tried to create a list but was not able to do make it work i have to less knowledge for this.

```
$applist = [PSCustomObject]@{
    appname = $listitem
}
#somecode
do{
    $appname = Read-Host "Which App you want to delete: [OneConnect]"
    $listitem += "*$appname*"
    #add $listitem to $applist except it is like **
    $counterT++
}while($appname -notlike "")

$applist
```

i want to display $applist all the entries except the clear one

It should look like

`*Zune*`

`*OneConnect*`

Comment: is there a reason you are creating a custom object that has the list in it? the more usual way would be to make a list as such ... [*grin*]

Comment: i have a problem understanding Arrays and lists in anyway in powershell, but somehow it would be crusial to get this done in my head

Comment: i see that you have been pointed to the excellent post by KevMar about arrays & collections in general. i highly recommend his "everything" posts ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the scope. Just declare the custom object within that will result in the display but you have to work on the logic of how you wish to see them (format). Give the below a try and you should be able to see the entries of your 
`read-host`

```
#somecode
do{
    $appname = Read-Host "Which App you want to delete: [OneConnect]"
    $listitem += "*$appname*"
    #add $listitem to $applist except it is like **
    $counterT++

    $applist = [PSCustomObject]@{
    appname = $listitem
}
}while($appname -notlike "")

$applist
```

Comment: is there a way to get my "logic" working i find it somehow complicated, and to have it in rows not columns

Comment: Enclosing an appname in asterisks makes IMO only sense in a comparison  with `-like` not as appending to $listitem of unknown type.

Comment: but this is how i actually need it in further use I'll edit my post for clarification

Comment: @Kevin: I haven't checked the logic. I just rectified the scope part for which you were not getting values. For logic part, I need to see what exactly the time of apps that you are expecting there. See for me, the PSCustomObject is not at all needed because what you are doing is simply can be added in an arraylist

Comment: this is where my "failure" is coming from, i dont have any idea of how arrays, list or the custom objects are working properly this is complicated as hell for me but never got it explaind properly

Comment: @Kevin: Understood the pain. Please go through [THIS](https://powershellexplained.com/2018-10-15-Powershell-arrays-Everything-you-wanted-to-know/). spend sometime.

Comment: Thank you for the link share i will read it through definitly maybe it will end the confusin in my head

Comment: @Kevin: Acceptance or Upvote would be appreciable if the answer helps you. Else unnecessarily I do not wish to keep it